# How to setup START_STICKY in service

Tags: android, service

I wish to ensure my service runs in the background even after a user closes the app (from the task manager or related). I am attempting to implement `START_STICKY` but do not know how to properly override the `startService` method to allow for this to work.

At present I am simply using the `startService` method to start and bind the `LoggingIn.class` to the `MessagingService.class` as:

`startService(new Intent(LoggingIn.this, MessagingService.class));`

I have researched that the method `onStartCommand` is the common location for implementing `START_STICKY`, but I have not found a need for it within my app as once the service has started I bind all other classes to it:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        imService = null;
        Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

and

```
    bindService(new Intent(GroupMessaging.this, MessagingService.class),
            mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

How can I properly implement `START_STICKY` and ensure that my service stays active or restarted even after the app closes?

Comment: If you use startService() and don't override onStartCommand() the default implementation already returns START_STICKY, which leads me to believe that you have unrealistic  expectations of what START_STICKY really does.

Comment: @Sauron: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Still researching, but unaware if this is the right course. The service is for a texting app and needs to always be on

Comment: So you are using a **started** service together with a **bound** service? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is return the `START_STICKY` flag in the `onStartCommand()` method:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    // several lines of awesome code

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Further considerations:**

If you use a `Service` without overriding `onStartCommand()`, it returns `START_STICKY` by default, although normally the code run by a `Service` is put in the `onStartCommand()` method.

That's it. You're done, go home.

Comment: What goes in the code block? Where is this to be placed?

Comment: `onStartCommand()` is the method in your `Service` where you put all the code you want your `Service` to execute

Comment: **START_STICKY** doesn't prevent the Service from being killed when user force-closes the app from task manager...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure that your Service continues running after being dismissed in task manager, is to make it a foreground service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    return  super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Returning **START_STICKY** alone is not the solution.